# lost my Facebook appid for my website

Tags: facebook, app-id

We registered our website with Facebook.

We then wanted to start using the Facebook Javascript API
to make use of the Facebook Feed Dialog (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

How can we find out what the appid was that we got?

Answer (score 2):

**Set up fb developer account(in-short)**

1. Go to the Faceboook search bar and type in "developer." When the Facebook Developer application comes up, add it to your profile.
2. According to new rules, your account must be verified. Please verify your account by adding your Mobile phone or Credit/debit card [here](http://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php)

3 simple steps to get facebook app ID

1. Go to [apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) in your facebook developer account
2. On the left side you will find the list of apps you have created out of them finding the required one should not be difficult, so click on that.
3. Then you will see the summary of that app, out of which the first one should be `App ID/API Key`

ta-da

I hope this helps

Comment: You just verified I REALLY have a problem.  Maybe I didn't create a 'Developer' type of Facebook account?  I log in to developer.facebook.com and click 'Apps' from the top right of the toolbar and I do not see any apps in a list on the left side.  How do I create a delevoper account and get an app id, god it's confusing.  Thought we already did it.

Comment: Please make sure you are using the same facebook account

Comment: We only made one login on Facebook, then we thought added our websiete as an app to it.  There are no clear instructions on how to get a new or retrieve an existing app id in the facebook documentation.  Should we delete the account and start over?  If so how do you create a 'developer' account on facebook?

Comment: I deleted the crud that kept coming up when I logged in then checked 'apps'.  Now when I log in I'm immediately taken to http://www.facebook.com/advertising/   -------  that makes me think we may have created a 'business' account on Facebook.  I'm not seeing what you're describing.  If we had simply created a regular 'end user' type of Facebook account, would we be able to register our app and get an app id so that our web site could use the FB 'feed dialog' ?

Comment: when you created an account did you fill in a form which looked like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/screenshot20120417at914.png/ ?

Comment: No -- we started here with the business page for our site:    http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10148/discussion-between-dhiraj-bodicherla-and-wantthebest)